# How to detect onDisconnected event in firebase when wifi is suddenly turned off?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a video chat application using Firebase Real time database. Everything was working fine but now there seems to be a little problem now. We relied on firebase disconnected event to change the status of user from online to offline which works fine under normal circumstances (User logs in, Uses the app and then close the browser/tab). But when using the app, if user's wifi is disconnected, the disconnected event is not fired and the user's status is online forever until wifi is turned on again and user closes the browser window or logs out of application.

I've tried using nodejs server along with socke.io for handling presence but it doesnot seem to work either.

```
database.ref().child(`users/uids/${user.id}/friends/${this.authUser.id}`).onDisconnect().update({
  isOnline:false,
})
```

I expected onDisconnect event to fire when wifi was turned off..
Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how `onDisconnect` works. Try something like this:

```
var userRef = dbRef.child('..path to user object in database');
userRef.onDisconnect().update({
  isOnline: false,
  isBusy: false
});
```

Note that `onDisconnect` can sometimes take 1-2 minutes to actually do its stuff.

If you need something faster, you could periodically write something like

```
lastOnlineTimestamp: {'.sv': 'timestamp'}
```

in your user path and make the other users check how old this timestamp is.

Related docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect#update

Comment: Yes this is what I am doing right now, and it doesnot work..I've edited the question.

Comment: @UjwalKadariya are you sure you did? I still see `database.ref.on('disconnect'...` in your question.

Comment: Thanks, now I have put my actual code there. I'll try that once and let you know.

Comment: @UjwalKadariya Sure. I assume `user` is the other person and `this.authUser` is "you". Maybe you would like to mark yourself as offline for all of your friends, not just this `user`. This could be done by an `update` like `{[user1.id+'/friends/'+this.authUser.id+'/isOnline']: false, [user2.id+'/friends/'+this.authUser.id+'/isOnline']: false}` etc

Comment: Ok onDisconnected is working after some time..Is there anything faster that this?

Comment: @UjwalKadariya You can implement your own logic. See the 2nd part of my answer. For example, make users try to write something every 10 seconds. If some user hasn't written anything in more like 20 seconds, they must be offline.

Comment: @UjwalKadariya If you actually do something like that,

DON'T just `write every X seconds`. That would make a large queue of writes to be synchronized when the internet is back, which is bad for many reasons.

What you should do instead is

`write once, then write again X seconds after any successful write`,

so that only one write will be added in the synchronization queue.